# Trapping probe request in universal windows app C#

Tags: c#, wifi, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I was wondering if it is possible, in a universal windows app, to monitor all the probe requests around my device. I read and tried several samples codes provided from Microsoft to locate AP, but what I would like to do is the opposite, looking for every devices that send the probe request.
I read that it is usual to use Wireshark, but it possibly does not support the monitor mode under windows, and furthermore I want to use it in an application (even if I could use TShark...).
Well, is there an API that could do the trick ? (I looked at Windows.Devices.Wifi, WifiDirect and Co)

Thanks !

Comment: No, it's not possible just using an application, you will need an NDIS6 driver which allows you to monitor traffic, something like winpcap

Comment: Thanks. So there is no native API such as windows.devices.wifi thar support that.... Top bad, it is so easy to retrieve AP, I wish it would have been easy too

Comment: How about npcap? It supports NDIS 6. Not sure about windows 10 though. https://nmap.org/npcap/. Or this. http://www.win10pcap.org/ which claims to support both NDIS6 and Windows 10.